# List figures with \listoffigures but don't show the figures themselves

Tags: graphics, floats, captions, tocloft, apa6

For a journal submission, I need a list of figure captions at the end of my manuscript but they explicitly asks not to include the figures themselves in the document.

I have added `\listoffigures` at the end of the document and it does what it does. But, now, how do I keep the figures from being rendered?

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}

% Essential manuscript parts
\title{Test}
\author{Test}

% Style list of figures
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Figure captions}
\cftpagenumbersoff{figure}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\itshape\figurename\enspace}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{.\space} \setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{0pt}
\settowidth{\cftfignumwidth}{Figure 10.\quad}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{Something}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{This is a figure.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{This is a figure.}
\end{figure}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Figure captions}
\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

I have tried the `comment` package and `\excludecomment{figure}` but that eliminates the figure list as well.

I've tried adding the following to the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=none,labelformat=empty,textformat=empty}
```

This indeed removes the figures and captions on the final pages but leaves empty pages. Is there a way omit the empty pages?

Comment: If you are willing to define figures with a macro instead of an environment, you can have a look at the `\holdFigures` macro of the `boxhandler` package.  It has a deferral mechanism.

Comment: In principle, I'd be willing to do that but in practice I can't. I'm writing the manuscript with interspersed R-code that creates the figures/tables and their environments.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that requires a change in the file for the final version with only the list of figures.

You keep the line

```
\nofiles\renewcommand{\processdelayedfloats}
```

commented out until you have the document in final form; the figures will be printed at the end. When your document is finished, uncomment the two lines and run LaTeX again.

Here's an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%%% Remove the next line if you want the figures at their place    
\usepackage[figuresonly,nolists,nomarkers]{endfloat}

\usepackage{lipsum}% mock text

% Uncomment the following line for the final version
%\nofiles\renewcommand{\processdelayedfloats}{}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Whatever}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Whatever}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{table}[htp]
A table
\caption{Something}
\end{table}

\lipsum[4]

\clearpage

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks good, but it doesn't quite work, yet. As evident from the MWE, I use the `apa6` class that sets the options for `endfloat` to handle both figures and tables. Under these circumstances you solution has a side-effect: all tables are also omitted (I need the tables). I have updated my example to include a dummy table.

Comment: Well, they don't require me to use `apa6`, but they require me to implement the formatting used in this class. Unfortunately, in my field it's not customary for journals to provide their own TeX-classes (in fact, most manuscripts are written in Word), so I have to settle for DIY solutions. I agree, this is not desirable, though.

Comment: @crash A manual solution would be to remove the final figure pages with some PDF editing software (`pdftk` comes to mind), or with a document that just does `\jncludepdf[pages=1-?]{filename}` (where `?` is the number of the last page with a table).

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it. I don't use the `endfloat` package.

Normal way to include figure

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4in]{somefigure.png}
\caption{some caption.}
\label{Fig: somefigure}
\end{figure}
```

%--------- modification ---------

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}

\begin{figure}
\centering
%\includegraphics[width=4in]{somefigure.png}
\caption[some caption.]{}
\label{Fig: somefigure}
\end{figure}
```

This suppresses the figure and its caption in main document but shows the caption in list of figures.

First suppress the figure by removing the `\includegraphics` command.
The caption label (Figure x., Table x. etc) is suppressed using caption package option, `\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}`. 
Note the `\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}` option suppress labels for all captions including tables.
The caption in `[]` brackets shows up in list of figures while the caption in 
`{}` (which is kept empty) appears below the figure.

With these steps the figure and caption are suppressed in main document but you still get list of figures.